# How many Wordpress SQL Queries per page?

Tags: query, mysql, page-specific-settings

I am on a shared hosting which has a limitation at MySQL queries per hour. My shows unable to connect to database because of this.

Can anyone tell me how many queries are per page on a wordpress site with default theme instaled on?

PS: I haven't any plugin installed.

Comment: Have you checked out this? http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Save_queries_for_analysis 

If you have custom queries that are eating resources, you might be able to cache them using a transient: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/set_transient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordpress uses a lot of plugins and is very query heavy but the in spite of that, the front page uses `59 queries` to generate itself. I think the default (on a vanilla WordPress install on the default theme) is `27 or something of that nature`. The larger the number of queries, the slower the page is going to load and the more load you are going to put on your MySql server. All of the above is true if you do not use inline or regenerative caching mechanisms.

If you want to know more go through this [link](http://weblogtoolscollection.com/archives/2008/07/12/how-many-queries-are-too-many/) and you can also calculate the number of queries using this plugin [Debug Bar plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/debug-bar/)

Comment: This is very anecdotal. Any specific number of queries is tied to the code, content, and configuration. Neither is count of queries generic performance indicator. 1 slow executing query can stress server more than 100 fast ones.

Answer (score 5):

Use [Query Monitor Plugin](https://querymonitor.com/).

This will tell you how many Queries along with the time taken by each, at what place it was called along with stack trace.

It will even tell you time taken for page generation.

As others told, the number of queries is not the right parameter, but having anything over 100 would not be a good indicator in general.

The Plugin is free and licensed under `GNU General Public License`.

To quote the author of the plugin:

> Query Monitor focuses heavily on presenting its information in a useful manner. For example, aggregate database query information is made available, allowing you to quickly determine poorly performing plugins, themes, or functions. It adds an admin toolbar menu showing an overview of the current page, with complete data shown in a panel once you select a menu item.

Sample output:

[image: Query Monitor Sample Output]

For more information, please see:

- [Query Monitor on WordPress.org](https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/)
- [Query Monitor on GitHub](https://github.com/johnbillion/query-monitor)
- [The Query Monitor blog](https://querymonitor.com/blog/)

Answer (score 4):

This is all depends on what queries do you run on a page, are you using simple or complicated queries etc. There are really no set minimum or maximum amount of queries to a page. You will need to look in context of your site specifically and weigh the amount of queries to what is actually happening on your page.

Wordpress can be quite harsh on resources with certain queries, so you will need to take that into account as well.

But in the end it all boils down to time vs queries. This should be your goal, if you can get the job done in less time with more queries, you should do it, you should not be hampered by a low quality host.

My advice, you should find an appropriate host that can handle your queries and not limits you or Wordpress because of normal functionalities.